# how can i solve webhosting fetel erro question?

Tags: php, html

Warning:

```
require(/home/srila588/public_html/../home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php): 
Failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: 
Uncaught Error: 
Failed opening required '/home/srila588/public_html/../home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php'
 (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/usr/share/pear') 
in /home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php:17 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/srila588/public_html/index.php(4):
 \require() #1 {main} thrown in /home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php on line 17
```

i expecting write instructions or video to solve my problem

Comment: What could this possibly have to do with `c++11`?!? Tag removed.

Comment: You need to go check your paths, you must have configured something wrong somewhere. `../` means go one level up - so the _actual_ path resulting from `/home/srila588/public_html/../home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php`, would be `/home/srila588/home/srila588/public_html/autoload.php` - and the duplication of `/home/srila588` in there is most certainly not correct.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that the scripts were uploaded in the correct mode - ASCII or Binary. Check the readme of your script to see any special instructions. Normally it should be ASCII

Check permission (chmod) values of the file or directory. The recommended permissions are 755 for folders and 644 for files

If you've added some additional configurations to your .htaccess file, make sure to double-check it and ensure that it doesn't contain any errors. To confirm whether it's an issue with the .htaccess file, just temporarily rename it

Prevent your PHP code from timing out - for that you need to add timeout rules directly to your PHP scripts

And the most important tip, search on Google for your script name + internal server error or website builder + error message. Most likely, someone already had the same issue and explained a solution online, f.e. WordPress error establishing a database connection

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).